# USB SATA hard drive enclosure

Tags: drivers, usb, drive

I'm trying to use a USB to SATA hard drive enclosure on 10.10. It shows up in the file manager, but I cannot open it or anything else. Is there a driver I need or some other configuration I must do to see it work?

Its a Rosewill external enclosure if that matters at all.

Comment: Why cant you open it? What happens when you try to open it?

Comment: Does it show up in 'lsusb', 'mount' and 'df -h' ?

Comment: "SPIF301 USB2SATA Bridge" is what it shows up as. I double click on it, and absolutely nothing happens.

It shows up under the file browser, but its won't mount, and GParted has no idea it exists.

Comment: df -h shows this:

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             228G  7.7G  209G   4% /
none                  997M  664K  996M   1% /dev
none                 1006M  356K 1005M   1% /dev/shm
none                 1006M  348K 1005M   1% /var/run
none                 1006M     0 1006M   0% /var/lock

Answer (score 1):

I mounted my external by making sure that the drive was partitioned in windows.. seems it needs a dos mount point..then linux would look at the drive and allow partitioning and formatting. Works great.